# Does the group that get created as part of team site also have group in Microsoft teams chat?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, team-sites, microsoft-teams

When I create a SharePoint site using the team template (rather than communication template), I get group/mailbox.

Does this group also exist in Microsoft teams chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a modern team site connected with Microsoft 365 group from SharePoint admin center, it does not create "team" in Microsoft Teams automatically.

However, you get an option on home page of your SharePoint team site to connect it with Microsoft Teams like:

[image]

When you click on "Add Microsoft Teams" > Continue > Add Team, it creates a new "team" in your Microsoft Teams which gives you General channel to collaborate with team members (Posts in channel, Share files, etc.).

**Documentation**: [Create a team site in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-a-team-site-in-sharepoint-ef10c1e7-15f3-42a3-98aa-b5972711777d?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: Who can access the teams chat? Is it only the group members and owners? Or even the visitors?

Comment: It will be accessible to M365 group owners and members.